# rails5 / params.merge causes errors about being insecure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-5

Having this syntax : `url_for(params.merge(locale: :en))`

Rails 5 blocks it, complaining about the following : `Generating an URL from non sanitized request parameters is insecure!`

What could be the up-to-date appropriate syntax, to get the same kind of result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just merge the local in `url_for`:

```
url_for(locale: :en)
```

It will reuse the current request parameters to generate the final URL.

Comment: ok i might see... `params.merge` is only useful if you have a bunch of drity `?param=1&param2=2&etc=ok`; but if you have clean routes `url_for`is enough, am i right ?

Comment: Even if you have params, `url_for` will preserve them.

Comment: I guess I'll go double-check what's 'merge' aims at

Comment: I just checked, url_for does not preserve params in Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `ActionController::Parameter` safety with

```
url_for(params.to_unsafe_h.merge(locale: :en))
```

I usually create a helper for this

```
def params_plus(additional_params)
  params.to_unsafe_h.merge(additional_params)
end
```

And then use it like

```
url_for(params_plus(locale: :en))
```

Other answers have suggested `url_for(locale: :en)` But this drops the existing request parameters, which is not what you want I believe.